# How To Merge an Arbitrary Number of Tuples in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have a list of tuples:

```
l=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
```

The list can be of arbitrary length, as can the tuples. I'd like to convert this into a list or tuple of the elements, in the order they appear:

```
f=[1,2,3,4,5,6] # or (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

If I know the at development time how many tuples I'll get back, I could just add them:

```
m = l[0] + l[1]  # (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

But since I don't know until runtime how many tuples I'll have, I can't do that. I feel like there's a way to use `map` to do this, but I can't figure it out. I can iterate over the tuples and add them to an accumulator, but that would create lots of intermediate tuples that would never be used. I could also iterate over the tuples, then the elements of the tuples, and append them to a list. This seems very inefficient. Maybe there's an even easier way that I'm totally glossing over. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) them (only creates a generator instead of reserving extra memory):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an `itertools` way to do it, but for the life of me I couldn't find it. Accepted.

Answer (score 10):

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
print sum(l, ()) # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: I always feel awful when I abuse `sum` this way. But that didn't stop it from popping into my head too.

Comment: What does `()` as the `start` value represent, or, how does this work?!  An empty tuple?

Comment: For longer lists this will be very much slower than chain.from_iterable; it's O(n^2). [That said, I often do it myself when I know the list size is small and bounded.]

Comment: @DSM: Yeah, chain is better. But still, another solution is always nice.

Comment: +1 for succinctness, but I accepted the chain answer as the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung: I had to look that up myself. If the sequence were empty, `sum` would return `0` rather than `()`. The `start=()` adds an empty tuple to the last tuple (resulting in no change) or, if the sequence is empty, is simply returned.

Comment: If start were 0, you'd get a type error, because you can't add int to a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

```
reduce(tuple.__add__, [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple(i for x in l for i in x) # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the pythonic generator style for all of the following:

```
b=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]

list = [ x for x in i for i in b ] #produces a list
gen = ( x for x in i for i in b ) #produces a generator
tup = tuple( x for x in i for i in b ) #produces a tuple

print list
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I just found this in the data structures tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. +1 for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
>>> list(chain(*l))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the values in a list using the `.extend()` function like this:

```
l = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
m = []
for t in l:
    m.extend(t)
```

or a shorter version using reduce:

```
l = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
m = reduce(lambda x,y: x+list(y), l, [])
```

Comment: Lists have `.extend(iterable)`. No need to create a new list from `t`.

Comment: @MattAlcock all unbound list objects will be cleaned by garbage collector, correct? sorry, if I didn't understand your question right.

Comment: @AndiDog thank you, didn't know about list.extend(iterable), variant with .extend should be better from any perspective