# How to join many "listed" tuples into one tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

There are few answers for the problem on [in Python, How to join a list of tuples into one list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269161/in-python-how-to-join-a-list-of-tuples-into-one-list), [How to merge two tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745199/how-to-merge-two-tuples-in-python), [How To Merge an Arbitrary Number of Tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401209/how-to-merge-an-arbitrary-number-of-tuples-in-python). All the answers refer to **list of tuples**, so the solutions provided there seem to be useless for me.

Here is my problem, I have a file with tuples listed like this:

> (1, 5)
>
> (5, 3)
>
> (10, 3)
>
> (5, 4)
>
> (1, 3)
>
> (2, 5)
>
> (1, 5)

I would like to join them in ONE tuple like this:

> ((1, 5), (5, 3), (10, 3), (5, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (1, 5))

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem: reading tuples from file into corresponding Python variables, or joining the variables you have in one? What have you tried?

Comment: why not add them all to a list, and then call the tuple function on the list to convert it to a tuple

Comment: Looks like you have a file full of _text_, not tuples.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My problem is explained below.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple(ast.literal_eval(x) for x in my_open_file if x.strip())
```

I suppose ...

Answer (score 1):

```
a = (1, 5)

b = (5, 3)

c = (10, 3)

d = (5, 4)

e = (1, 3)

f = (2, 5)

g = (1, 5)

tul = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)

print(tul)
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension as mentioned in your linked answers works with tuple() as well:

```
print tuple((1,2) for x in xrange(0, 10))
```

Leaving off the "tuple" or "list" at the beginning will return a generator.

```
print ((1,2) for x in xrange(0, 10))
```

Using [] instead of () is short-hand for list:

```
print [(1,2) for x in xrange(0, 10)]
```

The evaluation of the for statement is returning a generator, while the keywords or bracket are telling python to unpack it into that type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my problem: I want to know how many times a tuple appears in my 'result'. So I did this:

```
from collections import Counter
liste = [1,2,3,5,10]
liste2 = [[1,2,3,5,10], [1,2], [1,5,10], [3,5,10], [1,2,5,10]]
for elt in liste2:
    syn = elt # identify each sublist of liste2 as syn
    nTuple = len(syn)   # number of elements in the syn
    for i in liste:
        myTuple = ()
        if synset.count(i): # check if an item of liste is in liste2
        myTuple = (i, nTuple)
        if len(myTuple) == '0': # remove the empty tuples
           del(myTuple)
        else:
            result = [myTuple] 
            c = Counter(result)
            for item in c.items():
                print(item)
```

and I got these results:

> ((1, 5), 1)
>
> ((2, 5), 1)
>
> ((3, 5), 1)
>
> ((5, 5), 1)
>
> ((10, 5), 1)
>
> ((1, 2), 1)
>
> ((2, 2), 1)
>
> ((1, 3), 1)
>
> ((5, 3), 1)
>
> ((10, 3), 1)
>
> ((3, 3), 1)
>
> ((5, 3), 1)
>
> ((10, 3), 1)
>
> ((1, 4), 1)
>
> ((2, 4), 1)
>
> ((5, 4), 1)
>
> ((10, 4), 1)

Instead of having some elts N times (e.g **((5, 3), 1)** and  **((10, 3), 1)** appear twice), I would like to have a tuple(key,value) where value = the number of times key appears in 'result'. That why I thought I can join my listed tuples in one tuple before using Counter.

I would like to get 'result' like this:

> ((1, 5), 1)
>
> ((2, 5), 1)
>
> ((3, 5), 1)
>
> ((5, 5), 1)
>
> ((10, 5), 1)
>
> ((1, 2), 1)
>
> ((2, 2), 1)
>
> ((1, 3), 1)
>
> ((5, 3), **2**)
>
> ((10, 3), **2**)
>
> ((3, 3), 1)
>
> ((1, 4), 1)
>
> ((2, 4), 1)
>
> ((5, 4), 1)
>
> ((10, 4), 1)

Thanks